# Ejecutar un comando FTP desde java

Tags: java

Alguien sabe como ejecutar un comando en un servidor ftp desde java? usando la libreria Apache FTPClient

el comando es bin o binary, intenté con este comando pero no funciona me regresa un error 500 `500 unknown command quote site`

`ftpClient.sendCommand("quote site CYL PRI=10 SEC=10");`

Comment: En éste blog te lo explican todo de forma detallada: http://escribojava.blogspot.com/2011/07/lanzador-de-comandos-ftp-en-java.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En este caso de acuerdo a el error:

> 500 unknown command quote site

Indica que el [servidor no reconoce el comando](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.1.0?topic=codes-500-unknown-command-command) "quote" como un comando FTP valido.

Escribe en mayúsculas el comando, primeramente prueba:

```
ftpClient.sendCommand("HELP")
```

para asegurar no exista otro problema y posteriormente prueba con el comando inicial.

```
ftpClient.sendCommand("QUOTE SITE PRI=10 SEC=10 CYL ");
```

Comment: Es correcto Jorgesys, el servidor no reconoce ese comando desde FTP, se solucionó removiendo el QUOTE del sendCommand.  Muchas gracias :)